# MongoDB - Condition on sub documents using Linq

Tags: linq, mongodb, conditional-statements, documents

I'm using the mongo-csharp-driver to query my Mongo entities.
I have the following objects which are stored in the Mongo:

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Description{ get; private set; }       
    public List<Player> Players { get; private set; }

    public Table()
    {
    }
 }

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Username{ get; private set; }        
    public Player()
    {
    }
 }
```

When I'm trying to query the "Table" object by id or description, I get the appropriate results, but when I try to query by the list of player, I get null:

```
// Works ok
var tab1 = mongo.GetCollection<Table>().Where(g => g.Description == "Test");
// Always return null, although should return the same result
var tab2 = mongo.GetCollection<Table>().Where(g => g.Players.Count > 90).FirstOrDefault();
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: What is Count intended to be here?

Comment: Retrieve only tables with a certain amount of players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that [Count property](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+LINQ+Tutorial#CSharpDriverLINQTutorial-Countproperty%28arraylength%29) is translated into the [$size query operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24size).

From the linked Advanced Queries page you can see that:

> "You cannot use $size to find a range of sizes (for example: arrays
>   with more than 1 element)."

Comment: Got you. So if I get this straight, in order to achieve that I must have an additional property for the "PlayersCount" in the "Table" object and query it instead. Is this the acceptable workaround? -Is this treated as a bug in Mongo?

Comment: you are correct about what it takes and this is not a bug in Mongo - it's just how $size works.